# Прошу помочь более опытных. в php

Tags: php

У меня проблема , у меня уже есть рабочий код который связуется с сервером и получает от него инфу .
Но у меня не хватает опыта допилить код с разбивкой .
К примеру Ник игрока (стим айди) (время на сервере).
Я пробовал разные варианты но результата особо не добился, опыта еше мало еше на обучаюсь но очень интересно рыть код)Если кто поможет буду благодарен .

````
<?php
function source_query($ip){
    $cut = explode(":", $ip);
    $HL2_address = $cut[0];
    $HL2_port = $cut[1];

    $HL2_command = "\377\377\377\377TSource Engine Query\0";

    $HL2_socket = fsockopen("udp://".$HL2_address, $HL2_port, $errno, $errstr,3);
    fwrite($HL2_socket, $HL2_command);
    $JunkHead = fread($HL2_socket,4);
    $CheckStatus = socket_get_status($HL2_socket);

    if($CheckStatus["unread_bytes"] == 0)return 0;

    $do = 1;
    while($do){
        $str = fread($HL2_socket,1);
        $HL2_stats.= $str;
        $status = socket_get_status($HL2_socket);
        if($status["unread_bytes"] == 0){
               $do = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose($HL2_socket);

    $x = 0;
    while ($x <= strlen($HL2_stats)){
        $x++;
        $result.= substr($HL2_stats, $x, 1);   
    }

    // ord ( string $string );
    $result = str_split($result);
    $info['network'] = ord($result[0]);$char = 1;
    while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['name'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
    while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['map'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
    while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['dir'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
    while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['description'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}$char++;
    $info['appid'] = ord($result[$char].$result[($char+1)]);$char += 2;       
    $info['players'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;   
    $info['max'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;   
    $info['bots'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;   
    $info['dedicated'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;   
    $info['os'] = chr(ord($result[$char]));$char++;   
    $info['password'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;   
    $info['secure'] = ord($result[$char]);$char++;   
    while(ord($result[$char]) != "%00"){$info['version'] .= $result[$char];$char++;}

    return $info;
}
$q = source_query('xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx : xxxxx ');
$procent = ($q['players']*100/$q['max']);
echo "<br><div class='progress'><div class='progress-bar purple' style='width:".$procent."%;'></div></div>";
echo "<span style='float:left;font-size:10pt;'>".$q['players']." из ".$q['max']."</span>";
echo "<span style='float:right;font-size:10pt;'>".$q['map']."</span><br>";
?>```
````

Comment: А что если инфу передавать в формате json и далее json_decode, вроде так легче тебе будет.

Comment: глянь функции json_encode и json_decode, может быть тебе поможет.

Comment: Для начала неполохо было бы научиться хорошо форматировать код. Как правило если с кодом работают, то его чаще читают чем пишут/меняют. Поищите стандарты оформления кода (сейчас модны psr-1 и psr-12). Поясню почему я это советую - сейчас ваш код тяжеловато читать

Comment: По сути вопроса: Что по вашему должна делать конструкция `ord($result[$char]) != "%00"` ?

Comment: Тут немного другая задача,да с  json было по проше ,но рамки такие  что необходимо выполнить условие  на  тестовом сервере . У меня косяк в этой  части вышел чтобы вызвать построчно  инфу о   (игроках) и их айди. 
Применив к данным данным основной код который уже все это выводит по типу батл метрики в мониторинге.
Вот такая задача стоит .
Мне бы пару готовых примеров как это реализовали в различных вариантах дабы верно найти   добавить и оптимизировать в структуре.

Comment: + провести работу так сказать над ошибками ,Если можете покидать шаблончики буду не против сам порыть .

Comment: 1. Вы так и не ответили на мой вопрос; 2. Чтобы понять что творится в коде, неплохо было бы пару примеров входных данных и результатов. Повсеместное применение `ord()` совсем непонятно

Comment: tutankhamun 1
Для вывода служит в команде и запросе, прост не могу скинуть основную часть над которой работаю